# Monkey testing for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, testing, ios-simulator, monkey-testing

Is there a tool for monkey testing for iPhone? Like in the simulator.

Comment: I could lend you my chimpanzee, Mr. Higglesbottom, but I need to know how far away you are and how long you need him for.

Comment: I haven't had the best luck with chimpanzees; their large fingers are not very accurate on the iPhone's relatively small touch screen.  Smaller monkeys like Macaques work really well, though.

Comment: Another problem is their strength, They tend to crush the phones. Mine went through 3 devices.. (We had to let him go)

Answer (score 4):

We use anteater: http://www.redant.com/anteater

It's free and pushes itself as an iPhone port of Monkey testing.

Answer (score 4):

You should try [UI AutoMonkey](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-auto-monkey).

> UI AutoMonkey is a simple stress testing script for iOS applications that runs in UI Automation and Instruments.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a general scripting tool like QuickKeys to issue arbitrary user input commands automatically to the simulator.  Not perfect, but I think this will accomplish most of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try UISpec:

Its a behavior driven testing that drives the UI of Iphone. I think with additional layer on top, you can generate pseudo-random inputs.

http://code.google.com/p/uispec/